# Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: html, django

New to Django, and attempting to learn how to create a signup page through tutorial. Getting this issue despite following exactly what the tutorial is. Here is my html, views, and urls.

Code:

```
<body>
8       <header>
9         <h1>My Site</h1>
10        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
11          <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
12        {% else %}
13          <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> / <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
14        {% endif %}
15        <hr>
16      </header>
17      <main>
18        {% block content %}
19        {% endblock %}
20      </main>
21    </body>
```

Views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from mysite.core.forms import SignUpForm

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import url
from mysite.core import views as core_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^signup/$', core_views.signup, name='signup'),
]
```

Comment: Lets see your `urls.py`

Comment: where is your `views`and `url` for the logout ?

Answer (score 3):

You have not have added the logout url in your urls file,and that seems to be pointed to by a url tag in one or more of your templates. To make the it work you'd want to use the inbuilt django authentication,so you'd import logout from django.contrib.auth then add the logout url to your urlpatterns as below:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout #import inbuilt authentication for logging out 

urlpatterns = [
    #then add the url to your url patterns as below
    path('logout', logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^signup/$', core_views.signup, name='signup'),
]
```

I encountered a similar problem and those steps worked for me,hope it works for you and others too